# typo3 : Routing config for my own extension

Tags: typo3

I'm using typo3 v9.5 and have my own extension.

Actually I'm trying to get a clean URL with route Enhancers, it's my first time with it

I need an url like this :

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/{my-category}
```

and actually I have this :

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/{my-category}?tx_plugin_plugin%5BpageId%5D=102
&cHash=d6374a0e73ca3fde9c60edf88cfdf7cf
```

I have a second argument pageId, but it is possible to hide it on the url ?

this is my config.yaml :

```
Myext:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Myext
    plugin: Myext
    routes:
      - { routePath:
      '/{categorie-name}',
      _controller: 'Categorie::list',
      _arguments: {
            categorie-name: 'parentCategoryId'
                  }
         }
    defaultController: 'Categorie::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      categorie-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
```

I have another question, I saw some config about routing, and they have this settings :

```
    tableName: 'sys_category'
    routeFieldName: 'slug'
```

I tried to put slug to instead of 'title' but I got an error because I don't have this field on my sys_category table, it is possible to add this field on a core table of Typo3 ?

Error my table sys_category doesn't have slug field :

[image]

Comment: If the pageId is needed as a GET parameter, I wouldnt know. Maybe throw it in a session instead? sys_category does have a field slug already.. you can see in the database.

Comment: Why do you have a pageId in the URL if you don't need it?

Comment: I finally removed pageId arguments, I improved my code to works without it, but I checked my database, and  don't have the field slug, I update my question with screen of the error when I remplace routeFieldName: 'title' by 'slug' @JaccovanderPost

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude parameter you don't need in `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`,

```
'FE' => [
    'cacheHash' => [
        'excludedParameters' => [
            'pageId',
        ],
    ],
],
```

may be this will work for you.

Comment: I solved it with another way, but thanks it can help for future